# Spark Streaming ingestion on hdfs

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to ingest data in hdfs using Structured Streaming using this code:

```
val query = output
            .writeStream
            .format("csv")
            .option("path", "hdfs://hdfs_path")
            .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint")
            .start()
```

But that does not work due to the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: user

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: you need to give us more information from that error it is most likely your sparksession configuration is incorrect give us your initialization code also and test whether your spark-shell is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error suggests that you are not using `hostname` and port after `hdfs://` but you are giving path as `hdfs://user/...`

which tells *spark* that the `hostname` is `user`, which is not correct.

So find the `hostname` of the `namenode` and use that in the path,

so instead of

```
.option("path", "hdfs://hdfs_path")
```

you should be using

```
.option("path", "hdfs://hostname:port/hdfs_path")
```

Comment: thanks for the acceptance @ngi :) you can upvote too :)